# Call a function from inside a function?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
var A = function (id) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    function text () {
        return "Hello world";
    }
    this.other = function(){
        console.log(text());
    }
}
```

What if I wanted to add the `other` function from outside and still call the text() function like this:

```
(function(A){
    A.prototype.other = function() {
        console.log(text());
    }
})(A);
```

Is there any way to do that? I mean without having to change `function text(){}` to `this.text=function(){}`

Comment: **Why** don't you want to change `function text(){}` to `this.text=function(){}`?

Comment: Cuz I don't want it to be overwritten. `var a = new A(); a.text = function(){}`

Comment: Then your question should really be `How do I prevent a name from being overwritten`, and mention why [properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) are not sufficient. You should also probably consider whether you want to include code that randomly overwrites other libraries' names in the first place.

Comment: That's why I wrote, [edits welcome]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could attach `text()` method to `A` function which is still an object and then use it in `A.prototype.other` like this.

```js
var A = function(id) {
  this.id = id;
}
A.text = function() {
  return "Hello world";
}
A.prototype.other = function() {
  return this.id + ' ' + A.text();
}

var a = new A(123);
console.log(a.other())
```

Comment: If it works if i make it `a = new A("canvas_id");` than this is would probably be the solution. Can I?

Comment: And what is `"canvas_id"` ?

Comment: Are you asking me that because i wrote `var a = new A`, if you are, ofc you can if you aren't passing any parameters to constructor, you don't have to write `A()` you can just write `A` but its the same thing.

Comment: I am glad i could help.